# SELECT other rows based on one matching row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get related rows in a tag table based on one tag, where "related" means "having the same *area_id*". Example:

```
tag       area_id
--------  -------
turkey    1
stuffing  1
carrots   1
chicken   2
```

I want to get rows 'stuffing' and 'carrots' based on knowing 'turkey'. How might I accomplish this with one query (and/or subqueries) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to just do a self-join:

```
SELECT x.tag 
FROM tagtable x
JOIN tagtable y
    ON x.area_id = y.area_id
WHERE y.tag = 'turkey'
  AND x.tag <> y.tag
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how this might be modified to allow for additional tags? IE: WHERE (y.tag='turkey' OR y.tag='stuffing')?

Comment: That will do, if you want to avoid parenthesis you can use : y.tag in (...).

Answer (score 2):

if i'm reading your question properly, you know there is a 'turkey' tag and want your query to return every row that shares the same area_id but with a tag that is not 'turkey'. Right?
Try...

```
SELECT a.* FROM tagtable a,
(
SELECT * FROM tagtable WHERE tag = 'turkey'
) As z
WHERE a.area_id = z.area_id
AND a.tag <> z.tag;
```

hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer worked, though an EXPLAIN yielded a slightly less efficient query overall than @lennart's answer.